# Adding FileHandler to mlflow logger does not write all logs to file

Tags: logging, mlflow

I am using FileHandler to write logs from mlflow script but it does not write the logs from mlflow, only those I specifically logged:

preprocess.py (example, incomplete)

```
logger = logging.getLogger("mlflow")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("log.log"))        

logger.info("Reading data from {}".format(filepath))
data = pd.read_csv(filepath)
...
...
logger.info("Train data shape after preprocessing: {}".format(train_df.shape))
logger.info("Validation data shape after preprocessing: {}".format(val_df.shape))
logger.info("Test data shape after preprocessing: {}".format(test_df.shape))
...
...
```

log.log file

```
Reading data from /home/fsdf/projects/mlops_mlflow/data/dataexample.csv
Train data shape after preprocessing: (1709, 45)
Validation data shape after preprocessing: (488, 45)
Test data shape after preprocessing: (245, 45)
```

console display

```
2023/06/07 14:18:39 INFO mlflow: Reading data from /home/fsdf/projects/mlops_mlflow/data/dataexample.csv
2023/06/07 14:18:39 INFO mlflow: Train data shape after preprocessing: (1709, 45)
2023/06/07 14:18:39 INFO mlflow: Validation data shape after preprocessing: (488, 45)
2023/06/07 14:18:39 INFO mlflow: Test data shape after preprocessing: (245, 45)
2023/06/07 14:18:39 INFO mlflow.projects: === Run (ID '3a20a4db2d8f4211b38b783afa52b2d9') succeeded ===
2023/06/07 14:18:39 INFO mlflow.projects: === Run (ID '4aaa5e6577844bec88240a3982234eb6') succeeded ===
```

As you can see, there are some mlflow INFO logs (last 2 lines from the console) that are not written into the log file. How do I get them to be included?